# How do I combine two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have the following database structure:

```
`Products`
-------------------------------------
ID | ProductNo
-------------------------------------
1 | 3340
2 | 3450


`ProductVariants`
-------------------------------------
ID | MasterID (ref to `Products`.`ID`) | ProductNo
-------------------------------------
1 | 1 | 3341
2 | 1 | 3342
3 | 2 | 3451
```

How do I get the Products and their Product Variants with one query?

EDIT:

Desired result:

```
MasterID | IsMaster | ProductNo | VariantProductNo
1 | 1 | 3340 | null
1 | 0 | 3340 | 3341
1 | 0 | 3340 | 3342
2 | 1 | 3450 | null
2 | 0 | 3450 | 3451
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
INNER JOIN ProductVariants
ON Products.ID = ProductVariants.MasterID
```

Normally done with a single query for efficiency (you could have a query on the Products table, loop round the results of that and for each one do a query on the ProductVariants table, but it would be dog slow).

You could use a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead if you wanted products for which there were no variants

To go with your updated requirements, something like this (not tested so excuse any typos)

```
SELECT Products.MasterID, 1 AS IsMaster, Products.ProductNo, NULL AS VariantProductNo
FROM Products
UNION
SELECT Products.MasterID, 0 AS IsMaster, Products.ProductNo, ProductVariants.VariantProductNo
FROM Products
INNER JOIN ProductVariants
ON Products.ID = ProductVariants.MasterID
ORDER BY MasterID, IsMaster DESC, ProductNo
```

Comment: This will do it!! Is this a good way or may it slow down the execution   query?

Comment: I can't think of a more efficient way to do it (someone might know of a way though). Could possibly be made more efficient using UNION ALL rather than just UNION (a plain UNION eliminates duplicates which requires a bit of extra processing to check, while in this situation there can't be any duplicates due to the IsMaster field). Also it relies on VariantProductNo being unique (if not bring back the ID from product variants as well, and a matching null field in the first part of the query).

Answer (score 3):

You will want to join the two tables on their `Id = MasterId`:

```
select *
from products p
left join ProductVariants v
  on p.id = v.Masterid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3673b/2)

A `LEFT JOIN` will return all `products` even if they do not have a corresponding record in the `ProductVariants` table.

An `INNER JOIN` will return the records that appear in both table.

Here is a [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) that is helpful in learning join syntax.

If you have more tables to join, then you would use:

```
select *
from products p
left join ProductVariants v
  on p.id = v.Masterid
left join MasterArtikel m
  on v.MasterId = m.MasterId  -- you place the columns that join the tables here
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But if I now would count this, I m needed to add one, because the MasterArtikel is missing. How to do that?

Comment: @frgtv10 see my edit, you will just add another join and include the column names that join the tables.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you, but I want a result row for a `Product` and then for each `ProductVariant` a result row... how to get that?

Comment: Can you edit your OP with more details? Including more sample data and the desired result.

Comment: i added the desired result. does this result make sense for you? would you do it the same?

Comment: To do that I think you would need 2 queries unioned together. One query to get the master list and one to get the details.